# Piping user input and user output from a Python subprocess?

Tags: python, io, subprocess, python-logging

I am writing a python program to run another python program and pipe its input and output into different log files.

I tried creating this, but it seems to be closing the file prematurely:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

def main():
  program_filename = "calculator.py" 
  input_log_filename = "user_input.log"
  output_log_filename = "program_output.log"

  with open(input_log_filename, "w") as input_log, open(output_log_filename, "w") as output_log:

    print("Calculator program is running.")
    
    command = f"python3 {program_filename}"
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, bufsize=1)
    
    while True:
        program_output, _ = process.communicate(timeout=1)
        if program_output:
            output_log.write(program_output)
        print("Program Output:", program_output.strip())

        user_input = input("Enter input: ")
        if user_input.lower() == "exit":
            break

        input_log.write(user_input + "\n")  
        process_input = user_input + "\n"
        process.stdin.write(process_input)
        process.stdin.flush()
      
    process.stdin.close()
    process.stdout.close()
    process.stderr.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Two problems with your question. You wrote "it seems to be closing the file prematurely". You need to expand that to tell us what behavior you observed and what you expected. You are running a program named `calculator.py` but don't show us the program. I assume it works correctly when you run it directly from a shell prompt. I suggest replacing it with a trivial program that does nothing other than echo its input (and show us that program).